# Python OR-tools function does not work when called from within a Python package

Tags: python, package, runtime-error, swig, or-tools

I am new to Google OR-tools, and I have managed to get one of the examples to work when called from a `Jupyter Notebook`. However, when I take this working code and package it into a function in a python module I begin to encounter a `RunTimeError`.

I am using:

- **Python 3.6.5**
- **ortools 7.0.6546**
- **jupyter 4.4.0**

It seems I am missing something to make OR-tools available in my python package. I have looked up a similar error and come across suggestions to update the `distance_callback` function. But the function I am using is the suggested version anyway.

#### Working Code in Jupyter notebook

```
from ortools.constraint_solver import routing_enums_pb2
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp

def distance_callback(from_index, to_index):
    """Returns the distance between the two nodes."""
    # Convert from routing variable Index to distance matrix NodeIndex.
    from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
    to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
    return data['distance_matrix'][from_node][to_node]

def get_solution(manager, routing, assignment):
    index = routing.Start(0)
    output = [manager.IndexToNode(index)]
    while not routing.IsEnd(index):
        previous_index = index
        index = assignment.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
        output.append(manager.IndexToNode(index))

    return np.array(output)

# Create the routing index manager.
manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(
    len(data['distance_matrix']), data['num_vehicles'], data['depot']
)

# Create Routing Model.
routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)

transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(distance_callback)

# Define cost of each arc.
routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)

# Setting first solution heuristic.
search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()

search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
    routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC
)

search_parameters.time_limit.seconds = 30

# Solve the problem.
assignment = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)

x = get_solution(manager, routing, assignment)
```

#### Function contained in python module

```
def packaged_function(data):
    # Create the routing index manager.
    manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(
        len(data['distance_matrix']), data['num_vehicles'], data['depot']
    )

    # Create Routing Model.
    routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)

    transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(distance_callback)

    # Define cost of each arc.
    routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)

    # Setting first solution heuristic.
    search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()

    search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
        routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC
    )

    search_parameters.time_limit.seconds = 30

    # Solve the problem.
    assignment = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)

    return (manager, routing, assignment)
```

#### Calling function from Jupyter

```
from package_name.router import packaged_function
output = packaged_function(data)
```

When I perform the call this way I end up with some errors, namely:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
RuntimeError: SWIG std::function invocation failed.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ortools/constraint_solver/pywrapcp.py in <lambda>(self, name, value)
   2135         __swig_setmethods__.update(getattr(_s, '__swig_setmethods__', {}))
-> 2136     __setattr__ = lambda self, name, value: _swig_setattr(self, Assignment, name, value)
   2137     __swig_getmethods__ = {}

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ortools/constraint_solver/pywrapcp.py in _swig_setattr(self, class_type, name, value)
     70 def _swig_setattr(self, class_type, name, value):
---> 71     return _swig_setattr_nondynamic(self, class_type, name, value, 0)
     72 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ortools/constraint_solver/pywrapcp.py in _swig_setattr_nondynamic(self, class_type, name, value, static)
     54     if (name == "this"):
---> 55         if type(value).__name__ == 'SwigPyObject':
     56             self.__dict__[name] = value

SystemError: <class 'type'> returned a result with an error set

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
    233 
    234     # Solve the problem.
--> 235     assignment = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)
    236 
    237     return (manager, routing, assignment)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ortools/constraint_solver/pywrapcp.py in SolveWithParameters(self, search_parameters, solutions)
   3423 
   3424     def SolveWithParameters(self, search_parameters: 'operations_research::RoutingSearchParameters const &', solutions: 'std::vector< operations_research::Assignment const * > *'=None) -> "operations_research::Assignment const *":
-> 3425         return _pywrapcp.RoutingModel_SolveWithParameters(self, search_parameters, solutions)
   3426 
   3427     def SolveFromAssignmentWithParameters(self, assignment: 'Assignment', search_parameters: 'operations_research::RoutingSearchParameters const &', solutions: 'std::vector< operations_research::Assignment const * > *'=None) -> "operations_research::Assignment const *":

SystemError: <built-in function RoutingModel_SolveWithParameters> returned a result with an error set
```

Comment: From where does `distance_callback` comes from ?

Comment: I've taken it from the documentation here:
https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/tsp

Comment: maybe related to https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/1177 since ortools is a binary package what is your platform ? linux distro ? glibc version ? libstdc++ ?

Comment: can you try to create the distance callback in the body of packaged_function i.e. once the manager object is instancied...

Comment: The incorrect placement of the distance callback was the main issue here, thanks @Mizux for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must move the distance_callback definition inside the `packaged_function()`

e.g.

package_function.py:

```py
from ortools.constraint_solver import routing_enums_pb2
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp

def packaged_function(data):
    # Create the routing index manager.
    manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(
        len(data['distance_matrix']), data['num_vehicles'], data['depot']
    )

    def distance_callback(from_index, to_index):
        """Returns the distance between the two nodes."""
        # Convert from routing variable Index to distance matrix NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
        return data['distance_matrix'][from_node][to_node]

    # Create Routing Model.
    routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)

    transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(distance_callback)

    # Define cost of each arc.
    routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)

    # Setting first solution heuristic.
    search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()

    search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
        routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC
    )

    search_parameters.time_limit.seconds = 30

    # Solve the problem.
    assignment = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)

    return (manager, routing, assignment)
```

and test.py:

```py
from packaged_function import packaged_function as pf

def print_solution(manager, routing, assignment):
    """Prints assignment on console."""
    print('Objective: {} miles'.format(assignment.ObjectiveValue()))
    index = routing.Start(0)
    plan_output = 'Route for vehicle 0:\n'
    route_distance = 0
    while not routing.IsEnd(index):
        plan_output += ' {} ->'.format(manager.IndexToNode(index))
        previous_index = index
        index = assignment.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
        route_distance += routing.GetArcCostForVehicle(previous_index, index, 0)
    plan_output += ' {}\n'.format(manager.IndexToNode(index))
    print(plan_output)
    plan_output += 'Route distance: {}miles\n'.format(route_distance)

def main():
    data = {}
    data['distance_matrix'] = [
            [0, 2451, 713, 1018, 1631, 1374, 2408, 213, 2571, 875, 1420, 2145, 1972],
            [2451, 0, 1745, 1524, 831, 1240, 959, 2596, 403, 1589, 1374, 357, 579],
            [713, 1745, 0, 355, 920, 803, 1737, 851, 1858, 262, 940, 1453, 1260],
            [1018, 1524, 355, 0, 700, 862, 1395, 1123, 1584, 466, 1056, 1280, 987],
            [1631, 831, 920, 700, 0, 663, 1021, 1769, 949, 796, 879, 586, 371],
            [1374, 1240, 803, 862, 663, 0, 1681, 1551, 1765, 547, 225, 887, 999],
            [2408, 959, 1737, 1395, 1021, 1681, 0, 2493, 678, 1724, 1891, 1114, 701],
            [213, 2596, 851, 1123, 1769, 1551, 2493, 0, 2699, 1038, 1605, 2300, 2099],
            [2571, 403, 1858, 1584, 949, 1765, 678, 2699, 0, 1744, 1645, 653, 600],
            [875, 1589, 262, 466, 796, 547, 1724, 1038, 1744, 0, 679, 1272, 1162],
            [1420, 1374, 940, 1056, 879, 225, 1891, 1605, 1645, 679, 0, 1017, 1200],
            [2145, 357, 1453, 1280, 586, 887, 1114, 2300, 653, 1272, 1017, 0, 504],
            [1972, 579, 1260, 987, 371, 999, 701, 2099, 600, 1162, 1200, 504, 0],
        ] # yapf: disable
    data['num_vehicles'] = 1
    data['depot'] = 0

    (manager, routing, assignment) = pf(data)
    print_solution(manager, routing, assignment)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

output

```sh
python test.py
Objective: 7293 miles
Route for vehicle 0:
 0 -> 7 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 12 -> 6 -> 8 -> 1 -> 11 -> 10 -> 5 -> 9 -> 0
```

note: if I move `distance_callback` before `def packaged_function()` i can reproduce your error

Comment: Can you explain a bit more why this works? This fixed it for me too, but I can't understand why this behaviour is the case